# How to use distinct in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-db, zend-db-select

How can I use the `distinct` clause with `Zend\Db\Sql\`?

Comment: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Sql/Expression.php

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use an expression in your column selection.

```
$select = new Select('tablename');
$select->columns(array(new Expression('DISTINCT(id) as id')));
```

Comment: also $select->columns(array('id' => new Expression('DISTINCT(id)'))); Key will become alias

Comment: This is a hack, and wrong. "distinct" is a property of the row, not of the column. Once you want more than one column, this will not work at all.

Answer (score 35):

I found this very usefull solution on http://blog.abmeier.de/php/zf2-select-distinct

```
$sql = new Sql($adapter);
$select = $sql->select();
$select->quantifier('DISTINCT');
```

Comment: This is the proper answer and should be marked as answer

Answer (score 20):

While Mihai Dobre's answer is correct, I think you should use the constants provided by the framework instead of using a string literal. This will make your code more future-proof.

```
$sql->select()->quantifier(\Zend\Db\Sql\Select::QUANTIFIER_DISTINCT)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked best for me.

```
$select = $this->select()
          ->distinct()
          ->where('user_id = ?', $user_id);
```

http://webphplearn.com/blog/blogdetail/Distinct_in_Zendframework2